# fread seems to be reading the file from right to left

Tags: c, endianness

I have to read information from a bin file (they're 100k 6 bytes ethernet directions). I opened it with an editor and this is what is inside:
[image]

so using the code:

```
 FILE *ptr;
    ptr = fopen("ethdirs.bin", "r");
    if (!ptr){
        printf("Unable to open file");
    }
    uint64_t test;
    fread(&test, 6, 1, ptr);
    printf("result = %lx \n", test);
    fread(&test, 6, 1, ptr);
     printf("result = %lx \n", test);
    fclose(ptr);
```

should print 1B26B354A1CF which is the first 6 bytes direction. However, it prints:

> result = cfa154b3261b

which is exactly the direction I expect but read from right to left! Why is this happening and how should I solve it?

Comment: Look up ["endianness"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Spoiler alert: your computer is little endian, meaning the most significant byte of a 32-bit value is stored at the higher byte address in memory.

Comment: oh! I do know about it. Then the problem is how it is written on memory right? Not the way it is printed?

Comment: It's not a problem with how they are written in memory exactly. The problem is how you are "printing" it and you have to be aware of the memory order. If you want the bytes in memory order, print them one byte at a time, not as a whole 32-bit value with `%lx`.

Comment: oh, got it. I was "scared" because I have to do some operations with these directions so if they were written in "reverse" order of course I would get a completely different answer. So, nothing to be worried about. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got bit by endianness issues. Ethernet is big endian but your CPU is little endian.

Unfortunately there's no builtin to convert six bytes, so you have to do it yourself.

```
uint64_t test;
unsigned char convert[6];
fread(convert, 6, 1, ptr);
test =
    ((uint64_t)convert[0] << 40) |
    ((uint64_t)convert[1] << 32) |
    ((uint64_t)convert[2] << 24) |
    ((uint64_t)convert[3] << 16) |
    ((uint64_t)convert[4] << 8) |
    ((uint64_t)convert[5]);
```

Somebody might be able to figure out a faster bitbash, but you probably don't care.

Alternatively (depending on what you are doing) you could just print it in the endian you want like so:

```
unsigned char convert[6];
fread(convert, 6, 1, ptr);
//...
printf("%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n", convert[0], convert[1], convert[2], convert[3], convert[4], convert[5]);
```

I took the liberty of inserting the expected : separators in MAC addresses this time.

Comment: is it right that the first code says char but the second one says unsigned char? When I tried the first I got errors (not actual errors but non sense values). My code is working well with unsigned char tho

Comment: @MiguelDuranDiaz: Ah. Just a mistake I didn't catch.